# How to add legends to the barplot in R like shown in the below image?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, legend

I want to impleme[image]nt legend like tjhis

Comment: Hi! What's your question? What data do you have? What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I get it you want a legend with the label for the first key on the left and the label for the last one on the right. TBMK there is no out-of-the-box option to have the legend text on different sides of the keys.

But one option or hack to achieve this kind of legend would be "remove" the legend key labels for all keys except for the last and use the label for the first key as the legend title. To get the same style you probably have to set the same style for the `legend.title` as for the `legend.text` using theme options.

Using `mtcars` as example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(am, fill = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = function(x) { x[seq(1, length(x) - 1)] <- ""; x } ) +
  theme(legend.position = "top", legend.title = element_text(size = rel(.8))) +
  labs(fill = 4)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi sir @stefan maybe with your shiny expertise could you help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71268220/how-to-include-showmodal-and-modaldialog-like-popup-when-using-multiple-tabpan many thanks!